# sharepoint designer workflow email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have been using sharepoint designer workflows to send an email to a particular group when a requester  fills a form in my sharepoint site. the problem is some other groups are even getting emails although they are not present in my designer workflow. so can someone help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you selected proper SharePoint group already, one potential option would be that within the SharePoint Group there are not only AD Users but also AD Groups having email address configured for them which would automatically function as a Distribution list basically sending email to all members.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your response, but "To" and "cc" in the workflow addresses looks like help@services.com (its not a group)

Answer (score 0):

Check youe email string, verify your email group and confirm they are not part of that group

Comment: Thanks Paul I did that but no luck yet

Comment: You need to modify the setting of DL from a Distribution group to a Security Group and that's when SharePoint recognizes it.Try this and let me know if it works.